# CakePHP ACL and column permissions

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, acl

I'd like to use Cake's builtin ACL component for giving certain users permission to reading objects and specific columns in the database.

So lets say user1 is admin, he can see all the object and their columns, user2, only has the permission to read certain objects and for specific objects he can only see certain columns for that object.

For example:

```
User1 => Object1, column1, column2, column3, column4.
User1 => Object2, column1, column2, column3, column4.
User1 => Object3, column1, column2, column3, column4.

User2 => Object2, column3, column4
User2 => Object3, column1, column4
```

Is there a way to do this easily with the builin ACL?

Answer (score 1):

You should to use [this](http://www.alaxos.ch/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl) it easy to set up and ui friendly with ajax